# Searching Letter In Database Records / Mysql

Tags: mysql, string, parsing, substring

I want to make a search within a varchar column that return the rows which has letters in its last three part. Like:

id     name
---    -----
1       06jesq12g
2       06jesq123
3       06jesq126
4       06jesq12f

i want the records with id 1 and 4 because they have "letter" in the last three part. Not all of them are numeric. I hope i made my point, sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ... 
WHERE name REGEXP ('([a-z]..$|[a-z].$|[a-z]$)')
```